# D3 - The result of data loading can not output in console

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js. I tried requesting the data via d3.json as below and got the data successfully, but **my console outputs nothing.**

Could anybody tell me how can I do to solve it?

Thank you very much!

```
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json", function(json){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(json))  
})
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: try this `d3.json(url).then(function(data) { console.log(data); })`

Comment: It works! Thanks for your help!  @Narendra Jadhav